# NRE Account and a Ordinary Saving Account

Tags: india, banking, non-resident

Can a NRI maintain a NRE a/c for foreign remittances and a saving a/c in India (not NRO) for dealing with local expenses? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

> saving a/c in India (not NRO) for dealing with local expenses?

No an NRI cannot hold Ordinary Savings Account as this is in violation of FEMA [Foreign Exchange Management Act]. This should be Converted into NRO Savings account. Converting a Savings account to NRO is quite simple and please get in touch with your bank on the process ASAP.

Comment: And note that NRE account allows you to spend/send money for local purchases, transfers just like resident account. Only difference is NRE can accept deposits from Outside India only. Plus no taxes as of now.